# What are the differences between the 2009 and 2011 reprints of Twilight Struggle?

Tags: twilight-struggle

I'm interested in getting a copy of "Twilight Struggle", having enjoyed "1960: The Making of the President" and seeing that the former is currently the [top ranked game on BoardGameGeek](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/browse/boardgame).  It seems that there are two versions that are available to buy new at the moment:

- The 2009 Deluxe Edition reprint.
- The recently released 2011 Deluxe Edition, [available from GMT games](http://www.gmtgames.com/p-347-twilight-struggle-deluxe-edition-2011-reprint.aspx).

The slightly earlier reprint is rather easier for me to get hold of, but I'm having trouble finding out whether there are any significant differences between these editions.  Could anyone here give me an idea of how different the 2011 edition is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i can compare the specs on the GMT web site with my 2009 deluxe edition there are no differences.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've actually also received an email from GMT games now confirming that the 2011 deluxe edition is a straight reprint of the 2009 deluxe edition.

Comment: Oh, but if I understood correctly, the 2011 edition comes with a mounted board which could be purchased separately to upgrade the 2009 edition.

Comment: The 2009 deluxe edition has a mounted board and I do not think they changed the map graphic again.

Comment: There is now 2014 reprint and it too appears to be exactly the same.